# Python CPU and RAM memory usage

Tags: python, cpu, ram, psutil

I am writing a script that writes CPU and RAM usage, I want to add list every process using 1% CPU or RAM

```
import datetime ,psutil ,time ,subprocess

mem_usage = (psutil.virtual_memory())
cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
cmd = "WMIC PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

d_h = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
f = open('dane.txt', 'a')
f.write("DATE: "+d_h+'\n')
f.write("MEM USAGE: "+(str(mem_usage)+'\n'))
f.write("CPU USAGE: "+(str(cpu_usage)+"%"'\n'))
f.write("CPU PROCESS LIST: "+""+'\n')
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    f.write(str(proc.name)+'\n')
f.write(" "+'\n')
f.close()
```

I would like it to look like this

file.txt

```
DATE & TIME
CPU_USAGE: 45%
MEM_USAGE: 88%
PROCESS_LIST:
list all process usage 1% RAM or CPU
```

thanks in advance

Comment: which output are you currently getting?

Comment: in file.txt write                                                                                           
DATE: 2018/11/29 12:23:39
MEM USAGE: svmem(total=8483639296, available=3379355648, percent=60.2, used=5104283648, free=3379355648)
CPU USAGE: 76.4%
CPU PROCESS LIST: 
<bound method Process.name of psutil.Process(pid=0, name='System Idle Process', started='2018-11-15 10:02:47')>

Answer (score 1):

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    f.write(str(proc.name())+'\n')
```